# How to check if the optimization algorithm produces the correct result [SVM]

Tags: svm, gradient-descent

I have implemented the gradient decent algorithm for the SVM (linear case).

I would like to check if my implementation is correct. I see 3 possible solutions:

1. Write some unit tests for the code
2. Check the results using another tool (python libs)
3. Check if the estimated parameters have the expected distribution.

For the latter approach, I would like to know if there are any papers that provide some hint on the confidence interval of the estimated parameters of the SVM (it would be great for the case when kernel trick is applied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SVM the objective is convex, which means you will have a unique solution for each problem setting. There are many SVM libraries available, why not compare your results with the libraries' output?

For SVM your predictor is

$$
f(\mathbf x)=\sum_i \alpha_iy_iK(x,x_i)
$$

And you are trying to use algorithms to get all the $\alpha$. You can directly compare the $\alpha$ got from your algorithm with the $\alpha$ from the libraries.

Also if your interest is trying to verify your gradient decent works well, you can use many optimization toolboxes to optimize your objective function and compare results.

Your optimization problem should be 
$$
\max_\alpha \sum_i\alpha_i-\frac 1 2 \sum_i\sum_j \alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j K(\mathbf x_i,\mathbf x_j)
$$

You can calculate the Kernel matrix and feed it into a solver to get all $\alpha$

Many R solver can detect if the problem is convex and if the result is converge. Please check this [task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on Lagrangian duality. Many convex solvers will in some sense give you a certificate of optimality in the form of giving you both $x$ and the value of the multipliers $\lambda$. Let $L(x, \lambda)$ be the Lagrangian: Trivially, for *any* $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{\lambda}$:

$$ \min_x L(x, \hat{\lambda}) \leq L(\hat{x}, \hat{\lambda}) \leq \max_\lambda L(\hat{x}, \lambda) $$

Let us define: 
$$g(\lambda) = \min_x L(x, \lambda) \quad \quad f(x) = \max_\lambda L(x, \lambda) $$

$f(x)$ gives an upper bound on the optimal value of L. $g(\lambda)$ gives a lower bound on the optimal value of $L$. If $f(x) = g(\lambda)$, then $x$ *must* be a solution to the optimization problem!

It turns out that for convex problems that satisfy some kind of constraint qualification (eg. Slater's condition), that there exist $x$ and $\lambda$ such that $g(\lambda) = f(x)$, that is, strong duality (aka the saddle point property) holds.

Weak duality: (requires essentially nothing)
Since this is true for *any* $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{\lambda}$, it holds for specific values:
$$ \max_\lambda \min_x L(x, \lambda) \leq \min_x \max_\lambda L(x, \lambda)$$

Strong duality: (requires stronger conditions, eg. convex problem + Slater's condition)
$$ \max_\lambda \min_x L(x, \lambda) = \min_x \max_\lambda L(x, \lambda)$$